# Eliminate the "Upload" button in Webforms

Tags: webforms, theming

There is a way to eliminate the "Upload" button in Webforms, just adding an "attach" button that uploads the file automatically when you push "send", like in the image.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's worth to remember that file will be uploaded when you push form's submit button, if user haven't uploaded it yet.

Second, you could use [AutoUpload](https://drupal.org/project/autoupload) module:

> AutoUpload is a user interface (UI) enhancement that initiates automatic upload of files minimizing the number of clicks required by a user.
>
> Currently, users must select files, then press the "Upload" button. We found users often don't realize a button press is necessary and mistakenly think their image is uploaded when it's not.
>
> This module removes the extra button press and hides the "Upload" button via JavaScript for a quicker, automatic file upload. When JavaScript is not enabled, it falls back to the "Upload" button.

I must admit that this module conflicted with my custom modules and themes, but as a code sample it was perfect. It's GPL, so tailoring it to your custom needs is perfectly legal.

Comment: So if I hide the rest of elements with css and I only show the "Browse" button, when the user will submit it, it will work? (Thanks)

Comment: @capitanmelao Worked for me with 7.20 and Form API forms all right. Your specific mileage may vary, but as far as I know it should work. Please test, and if it'll fail feel free to comment and request update on this answer :) Anyway I highly recommend AutoUpload - it makes things faster, browser uploads things while user is still editing other fields, so it does not need to upload anything big when user finished -> Less time from submit click to result page.

Comment: Thank you! I´m hiding now the elements, now.. AutoUpload could be integrate in my content type Webform? (Anyway I will try all of this, I will let you now, thank you very much!)

Comment: Will it support Webform ?

Comment: @Bala it integrates with managed file widget at Form API level, so unless Webform integrates with it in a conflicting way, it will. See my last sentence.

Comment: @Mołot You are right, I just did try it, it works! but now I have an off topic question, I am transform all the entire "Browse No file selected" To a button like "Submit" http://nellens.com/home/content/contact, using css, I don´t know if this is possible, many thanks again.

Comment: @capitanmelao if it works, consider accepting ;) For side questions, please ask them - here or on Webmasters or Stack Overflow, wherever they fits. This site is not a forum :)

Comment: * I meant "ask them as a questions, using the Ask question button".

Comment: With pleasure, I am new in this site, thank you very much, it did solve my problem.

Comment: @capitanmelao No problem. Accepting is in no way obligatory. It only means "I tested it, worked for me, alternatives are still welcome but I have a solution I needed to keep going". It helps future readers to know if answer was tested, and future answerers to not search for what's already found. So use it when it's due, but don't hesitate to **not** accept a helpful answer that does not really works and only provides useful hints.

Comment: @Mołot Actually your answer solved my problem because I did not know if the field did depend on the Upload button. The CSS this is another question that I already open it, thanks again!